# Keras Autoencoder Input Image Size

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

Consider this Autoencoder:

```py
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.models import Model

class ConvAutoencoder:

    def __init__(self, image_size, latent_dim):

        inp = Input(shape=(image_size[0], image_size[1], 1))

        x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inp)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        # at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

        d = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)

        decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(d)

        self.model = Model(inp, decoded)
        self.encoder = Model(inp, encoded)
        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam')

        print(self.model.summary())
```

I instantiate it with

```py
ConvAutoencoder(image_size=(32,32), latent_dim=10)
```

which prints

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 32, 32, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 8)         1160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 8, 8, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 16, 16, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 28, 28, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 1)         145       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,385
Trainable params: 4,385
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

As you can see, the input image size is `(32,32)` but the output image size is `(28,28)`.
* Question 1: How can I change the architecture of the autoencoder such that the output image size becomes `(32,32)`?
* Question 2: As you can see, the class expects an argument called `latent_dim`. Currently, this argument is unused. Is there an easy way of "forcing" the autoencoder's latent dimensions down to a certain number? E.g. adding a fully connected layer in the middle or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1

Well, you forget a `padding='same'` in the last upsampling.

It should looks like this

```
        # at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

        d = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)

        decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(d)
```

> Question 2

Do you mean the kernel? Then what about

```
        x = Conv2D(latent_dim*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inp)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(latent_dim*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv2D(latent_dim, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
        # at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

        d = Conv2D(latent_dim, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(latent_dim*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
        d = Conv2D(latent_dim*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(d)
        d = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(d)
```

But if you meant you want the middle layer to has a specific kernel size then you can replace the `MaxPooling2D` to `Conv2D` with stride like this.

```
encoded = Conv2D(latent_dim, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(x)
```

Actually you can remove all the `Maxpooling2D` and add the `strides=2` to all the `Conv2D`.